# Adding website to IIS

Tags: iis, web, localhost

So, I did something and my localhost website gave me a 500 error. Couldn't figure it out so I figured I'll delete the website in IIS and then re-add it. Apparently that was a mistake. I can't see the added website locally anymore. I seem to recall having to add a permission or something to be able to view it in localhost but for the life of me I don't remember what setting that was and I can't find it online. Any ideas? My other local website still displays fine ... Using Windows 8 IIS 8.5

I'm simply going to Add Website > putting in the site name and changing the port number. I've left the IP address alone to All Unassigned (I just want to view in as localhost:24)

Answer (score 0):

Adding website in IIS:

```
1. Right Click the Sites Folder image.
2. Add website.
3. Enter Site name.
4. On physical path textbo, Locate where do you want to store your website.
5.Assign a port.
```

then done.

After creating.

```
1. Select website created.
2. Open Directory Browsing.
3. On the right side click disable.
```

Make sure in application pool that your website has same framework set up.